# keydispatchingtimedout when application braught to background for 1 minute

Tags: android

In my code I have calls to some native c++ methods. All works fine. But when I tested my application on HTC Evo 3d I am getting issues. When I put my application in background for more than 1 minute and come back, the application gets stuck at the native function calls.It doesn't get executed and I get 'Application not Responding dialog'(ANR keydispatchingtimedout). This issue is observed only on HTC Evo 3D. On other phones it works fine. What can be its reason?

Comment: Key Dispatch timeout error comes when there is alot of processing on phone, and your event is missed by processor, and after a certain time it throws exception.

Comment: Event is missed means what happens exactly?How can I resolve it?